# how can i create a HashMap to iterate inside lambda function?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

Is there any way to create this hashmap inside the lambda function?

```
        Map<SaleStatus, Long> sales = new HashMap<>();
    saleStatusCounters.forEach(saleStatusCounter -> sales.put(saleStatusCounter.getStatus(), saleStatusCounter.getMatches()));
```

Something like this:

```
        saleStatusCounters.stream()
            .map(obj -> new HashMap<SaleStatus, Long>().put(obj.getStatus(), obj.getMatches()))
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(???)));
```

Comment: Read [the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-)....

Comment: What are you actually trying to do here? Why is `Collectors.toMap` not sufficient?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code is fine as is. You can, nonetheless, use streams and [`Collectors.toMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-) to get the result you want:

```
Map<SaleStatus, Long> sales = saleStatusCounters.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(obj -> obj.getStatus(), obj -> obj.getMatches()));
```

Note: this works as long as there are no collisions in the map, i.e. as long as you don't have two or more sale status counter objects with the same status.

In case you have more than one element in your list with the same status, you should use the overloaded version of [`Collectors.toMap` that expects a *merge function*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-):

```
Map<SaleStatus, Long> sales = saleStatusCounters.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
        obj -> obj.getStatus(), 
        obj -> obj.getMatches(),
        Long::sum));
```

Here `Long::sum` is a [`BinaryOperator<Long>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/BinaryOperator.html) that merges two values that are mapped to the same key.

Comment: Or `SaleStatus::getStatus, SaleStatus::getMatches`?

Comment: @chrylis Well, I don't have the name of the class, `SaleStatus` is what the `getStatus()` method returns.

Comment: Right, I've lived in Groovy land so long that's all just `it.status` to me!

Comment: @chrylis Yes! Groovy is so expressive. I'm learning it, though I don't actually work with it.